# in_array function, why this doesn't work?

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate a string to an array of numbers. If the string only contains numbers then the function should validate, but in_array isn't working, any suggestions?

```
$list = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$word = 'word';
$split = str_split($word);
foreach ($split as $s) {
    if (!in_array($s, $list)) {
        print 'asdf';
    }
}
```

here is the class:

```
class Validate_Rule_Whitelist {

public function validate($data, $whitelist) {
    if (!Validate_Rule_Type_Character::getInstance()->validate($data)) {
        return false;
    }
    $invalids = array();
    $data_array = str_split($data);
    foreach ($data_array as $k => $char) {
        if (!in_array($char, $whitelist)) {
            $invalids[] = 'Invalid character at position '.$k.'.';
        }
    }
    if (!empty($invalids)) {
        $message = implode(' ', $invalids);
        return $message;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: There's *much* better ways to validate a string only contains numbers

Comment: I have to use the whitelist class because other classes rely on it, unless you have a better suggestion

Comment: That is probably a good indication that the approach to this should be different. Maybe have a factory produce the validator you need for that situation.

Comment: thats a good idea, but I'm not familiar with any built in whitelist characters functions

Comment: I guess I could use filter_var for most things

Comment: Instead of **in_array**, consider **preg_match**.

Comment: You can use that, regular expressions, and even some built in PHP functions make validation easy.

Comment: can you build a regular expression at runtime?

Comment: what would be a regular expression that is basically a list of valid characters, something like: /[abc123g]/

Comment: @user3207727: of course

Comment: regular expression are greek to me, I guess it's time to get into the nitty gritty, even though they are the devils work, haha

Comment: $white = '/[';
foreach ($whitelist as $w) {
 $white .= $w;
}
$white .= ']/';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in_array comparison with loosely typed values is somewhat strange. What would work in your case is:

```
$list = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$word = 'word';
$split = str_split($word);
foreach ($split as $s) {
    if (!in_array($s, $list, true)) {
        print 'asdf';
    }
}
```

This compares strings with strings and results in no surprises. 
**But**, as noted in the comments already, this is quite wrong way to do things and it is much better to use **filter_var() or regular expressions**** to achieve what you're trying.

Comment: what to you mean the wrong way, not to be disagreeable, but, filter_var is fairly limited (esp for whitelists) and regular expressions are just hairy imho

Comment: It seems wrong because you're checking POST data. Therefore there are two options - 1) either you're checking for content (e.g. is this value 'blue' or 'green' ?) in which case in_array() is the way to go (but then you're comparing whole strings and shouldn't have any problems). 2) or, you're checking only for form (e.g. is this value a number?) in which case regular expression or filter_var() is the way to go. Whitelisting individual characters just doesn't make any sense in any context I can think of. Too me it seems you're looking at the problem in a wrong way (or don't understand regexps).

Comment: i guess i figured to check each character against each other was the solid way to go, probably only because I don't understand regexps, the word that was key was whitelist, regardless of the technique, I think I would have gotten better results if I had posted the code first and explained a little more clearly...

Comment: currently I'm working on a project and have little interest in learning regular expressions because it seems to me there is almost always something wrong with whatever I come up with and since I'm developing I'm planning on re-inventing the wheel for originality sake whenever possible, so regex and me just isn't a fit right now, I do realy appreciate all of the advice, and not one but several answers make sense under different circumstance, im still working on it and if anyone wants the completed code or just want to generally school me let me know, Ill check back here and we can exchange info

Comment: ended up converting all integers to a string (Odin's) and works for strings with numbers list and numbers with string list

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
<?php

$validate_me = '123xyz';

if(preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $validate_me, $matches))

print "non-digit detected";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's ugly as sin but it works, no elegant solution here, just a double loop, if you see any problems please let me know

```
$match = array();
foreach ($data_array as $k => $char) {
    foreach ($whitelist as $w) {
        if (!isset($match[$k])) {
            if ($char === $w) {
                $match[$k] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isset($match[$k]) || $match[$k] !== true) {
        $invalids[$k] = 'Invalid character at position '.$k.'.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update: add the $type = gettype ... settype($char, $type) to allow === to function correctly when checking for integers

```
foreach ($data_array as $k => $char) {
    foreach ($whitelist as $w) {
        if (!isset($match[$k])) {
            $type = gettype($w);
            if (gettype($char) !== $type) {
                settype($char, $type);
            }
            if ($char === $w) {
                $match[$k] = true;
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: update:   foreach ($data_array as $k => $char) {
   foreach ($whitelist as $w) {
    if (!isset($match[$k])) {
     $char = (string) $char;
     $w = (string) $w;
     if ($char === $w) {
      $match[$k] = true;
     }
    }
   }